# Mule 4 - How to set Session ID for JMS Connector

Tags: jms, mulesoft, azure-servicebus-queues, sessionid, mule4

I have a requirement where I need to use Azure Service Bus Queue which follows FIFO pattern in Mule 4. As per requirement, I'm using **JMS Connector** instead of **Microsoft ASB connector**.

The ASB Queue has session enabled. But I don't know where in the **JMS connector** the session ID should be specified.

I tried setting it under **JMSX properties** ---> **Group Id**, but it is not working.
Also I don't know what kind of value needs to be set in **Group Seq**.

On JMS connector "**On New Message**" , I am getting the following error:

> An error occurred while creating the consumers for destination
> [QUEUE:poc-session-queue]: It is not possible for an entity that requires
> sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver.

Any thoughts on how it needs to be configured ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The  MuleSoft connector is non-sessioned. Sessions allow FIFO pattern and guaranteed message order to be implemented, but require sessionID client connection.

Note that a settings like Sessions support cannot be modified once it's set.
You will need to drop the queue and re-create.

Please refer [Configure JMS Connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/jms-connector/1.7/jms-studio-configuration#configure-input-source) , [New Messages Using the JMS Connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/jms-connector/1.7/jms-listener#listen-for-new-messages-from-a-queue) and [Message sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions)